# Are there any drawbacks to using head.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, head.js

Things I am aware of:

1. Screen flicker if scripts alter styles / content (not an issue for me as I currently load scripts at the end of the page and so have workarounds already)
2. Inability to detect script load failure (not *too* concerned about this either as everything I develop is required to work with or without javascript. Might affect my workarounds for item 1 but happy with this risk)

It **looks** to be a very good option to me but I am hoping for some references (feel free to say only positive things!) before I invest time in incorporating it into my next project.

Currently we develop mid-to-large sized sites with, generally, a moderate amount of Javascript (although this is growing rapidly). We also use the jQuery library for the bulk of our Javascript.

Anyone have any experience? Good or bad! :)

P.S. for those interested [this is head.js](http://headjs.com/test/headjs.html)

Comment: Until I figure out a better way to load stuff before the DOM finishes rendering, I'm hiding content initially and then calling `show()` in `head.ready()`. This way, there's still a flickr, but there's only one flash and the content isn't half-rendered for a split-second.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope. As long as you put any code that is dependent on the loading files inside head.ready {} then you will not face any problems with your code.

Comment: Thanks Phil - have you use it yourself before? I'm suspect of anything that looks this simple! :)

Comment: Is it possible to load commonJS modules using headJS?

Answer (score 9):

Here is my conclusion for head.js, I have done some benchmarks myself:

http://blog.feronovak.com/2011/03/headjs-script-is-it-really-necessary.html

It is subjective opinion and benchmarks are not by any means scientific.

Answer (score 4):

I was/am interested and thinking of maybe also using head.js BUT i found something not so nice: In the url that you gave me there are three tab buttons:

```
SCRIPT          SCRIPT SRC     head.js 
SRC in head     on bottom      on head
```

Shift+Ctr+Refresh gives very little differences for me  (+/-10ms between the three @ 120mbit line, firefox 3.6.13)

When I use Ctr+R refresh, the results on the head.js are consistently 100ms slower than the other two versions without head.js... **So, its NOT always faster.**

Comment: for me headjs is consistantly around 120ms but the rest are between 300-1k ms.

Comment: @Raynos, did you use Ctr+R , Ctr+F5 or Ctr+Shift+R?

Comment: all of them. of course ctrl+shift+r/f5 was slower on normal but doesnt make a difference on headjs.

Comment: Interesting! In your case head.js _DOES_ make things worhtwhile... perhaps its my browser thats not behaving as it should. Naughty Foxy!

Answer (score 1):

There would be no problem on using jquery or javascript library heavily. Try to main each library as unique.

I am using prototype, scriptaculous, jquery and many more jquery additional plugins. I faced an error while loading entire scripts. Then i found out its due to $ sign which is an important parameter of jquery and prototype.

i had used

```
    $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//jquery codes here
})
```

**So keep your script library unique**

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this is good advice but I'm not certain it is entirely what I'm asking. I'm looking for any issues specific to head.js rather than using multiple libraries in general :)

Comment: I just shared my problem i faced. to save u in your project.

Answer (score 0):

`head.js()` gave a problem to my pages. None of my `asp:button` OnClick events were working. But if I include the scripts in the traditional way (`<script type="text/javascript src=""`) then the events worked perfectly. I tried `EnableClientScript = "false"` and also `CausesValidation="false"`. But nothing worked. Finally just scrapped the head.js idea since it did not make a lot of difference to my page load time, anyway.